# Oracle Merge row by row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, merge

Sorry if i don't format everything correctly, it's my first time posting here, and sorry for bad english.

I have a big query that returns something like this :

```
col1 | col2 |col3|col4
==========================
A    |A1    |A2  |01/01/20
A    |A1    |A3  |01/02/20
A    |' '   |' ' |20/02/20
B    |' '   |' ' |01/01/20
C    |C1    |C2  |01/01/20
C    |C1    |C3  |01/02/20
```

And i want to insert this result into a table like this :

```
col1 | col2 |col3|col4
==========================
A    |A1    |A3  |01/02/20
B    |' '   |' ' |01/01/20
C    |C1    |C3  |01/02/20
```

I tried something like:

```
MERGE INTO dest_table d
USING (SELECT ....) a 
on a.col1 = d.col1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
WHEN MATCHED THEN IF col2 = ' ' THEN do nothing ELSE compare date and keep the most recent one
```

When i do this, it insert every rows

How i want it to work is like :

- Insert "A;A1;A2" because NOT MATCHED
- "A;A1;A3" IS MATCHED, because "A" was just inserted previously, so enter the "MATCHED" case
- "A;' ';' '" same as the previous one

Can i do something like that with "MERGE INTO" or should i try another method ?

Comment: Do you want to insert the *last version* of the key `col1` based on the date in `col4`? If so use something like `rownum() over (partition by col1 order by col4 desc) = 1` for filter.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT col1,
                FIRST_VALUE(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 
                                        ORDER BY CASE WHEN col2 = '  ' 
                                                      THEN DATE '1980-01-01'
                                                      ELSE col4
                                                      END DESC) col2,
                FIRST_VALUE(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 
                                        ORDER BY CASE WHEN col2 = '  ' 
                                                      THEN DATE '1980-01-01'
                                                      ELSE col4
                                                      END DESC) col3,
                FIRST_VALUE(col4) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 
                                        ORDER BY CASE WHEN col2 = '  ' 
                                                      THEN DATE '1980-01-01'
                                                      ELSE col4
                                                      END DESC) col4
FROM test
ORDER BY col1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7a05d1639b7ad1459b82e061e577c991)